# Starts of plagued or starts of plaguing

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, grammaticality-in-context, grammatical-number, grammar-myths

> After a rigged vote, the new government **starts off plagued** by illegitimacy and a mounting financial crisis.

> After a rigged vote, the new government **starts off plaguing** by illegitimacy and a mounting financial crisis.

What is the difference in terms of grammar between starts off plagued and starts off plaguing? When to use a past or present participle after start off? Actually the point asked was the query of the usage of past participle 'plagued'. Like,

> He starts to work.

> He starts working.

But not

> He starts worked.

But in the above mentioned query, we see  'After a rigged vote, the new government **starts off plagued** by illegitimacy and a mounting financial crisis. ' which seems little explainable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Senses 5 and 6 explain the verb plague](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/plague):

> 6. VERB
>    If someone plagues you, they keep bothering you or asking you for something.

> 5. VERB
>    If you are plagued by unpleasant things, they continually cause you a lot of trouble or suffering.
>    She was plagued by weakness, fatigue, and dizziness.

The OP's example hence should use **plagued**.

> After a rigged vote, the new government starts off [**plagued** by illegitimacy and a mounting financial crisis].

The new government is troubled; it is not the one troubling others.

Edit

*plaguing* could be used in a different context:

> The autocratic government starts off its term with harsh policies, **plaguing** its people.

Edit

*starts off plagued* is not a constituent; the constituent with *plagued* is *plagued by illegitimacy and a mounting financial crisis*, which is adverbial.  We may substitute it with another adverb, and the sentence still makes sense.

> ... the new government starts off [badly].

Another example could be

> The team starts off [awarded with an immediate yellow card].

OP's comments *He starts to play* and *He starts playing* are of different constructions. The infinitive *to play* and the gerund-participle *playing* are complement of *starts*.  Whereas "The new government starts off plagued." would be ungrammatical.

Comment: He starts to play. He starts playing. But not, he starts played. Just want to know the grammar  rule behind the usage of 'starts off plagued'.

Comment: I have elaborated my answer.  Hope it's clearer now.